# Why is the passed argument "not defined" in the exec(), even though the argument is defined in the same function?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, lambda, exec

I'm trying to dynamically create pages when each button is pressed. In the following code I pass the canvas of the current page into the next function so that it can be deleted ( preventing multiple pages open at the same time), but I'm getting an error: "File "", line 1, in  NameError: name 'menu_canvas' is not defined".

```
def gtpath_menu(canvas):

    menu_canvas = Canvas(gui, width=1480, height=920)
    menu_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    path_create_button = Button(gui, text="Go To Path Creation!", font=("Helvetica"), bg="white", padx=10, pady=10, border=5, command=lambda:path_create_menu(menu_canvas))
    with open("Paths.csv",newline='') as save_file: 
        reader = csv.DictReader(save_file)
        read_list = []
        for row in reader:
            read_list.append(row)

    path_name = ""
    path_list = []
    for dict in read_list:
        if path_name != dict.get("Path Name"):
            path_name = dict.get("Path Name")
            path_list.append(path_name)
        else:
            continue
    #button creation
    x = 0
    while x < len(path_list): #PROBLEM IS HERE
        exec("button{}=Button(gui, text=path_list[x], font=(\"Helvetica\"), bg=\"white\", padx=10, pady=10, border=5,command=lambda:path_page(menu_canvas))" .format(x))
        exec("menu_canvas.create_window(100, (300 + ({}*100)), anchor=\"nw\", window=button{})".format(x, x))
        x += 1  
    menu_canvas.create_image(0,0, image=path_img, anchor='nw')
    menu_canvas.create_text(100, 200, text="Choose Your Path Below", font=("Helvetica",30), fill="white", anchor="nw")

    menu_canvas.create_window(600, 200, anchor="nw", window=path_create_button)
    canvas.forget()
```

The button in the above while loop is supposed to call the following function while passing (menu_canvas) as an argument:

```
def path_page(canvas):

    canvas.forget()
    path_canvas = Canvas(gui, width=1480, height=920)
    path_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    path_canvas.create_image(0,0, image=create_img, anchor ='nw')
```

I wanted the button (on button press) to call path_page(), which would create a new page with the mentioned picture and size. The code is supposed to dynamically create a page for each new button made.(Buttons are made after reading data from a another save file)

Comment: This might be a case of [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables). Why use `exec` in the first place, rather than a list or dict of buttons?

Comment: `exec` is a newbie trap. It's got a minefield of weird limitations and undefined behavior that make it tricky to use even for experienced programmers, but it *looks* like it does exactly what newbies think they need. Pretend it doesn't exist - there is almost always a better tool for the job.

Comment: @user2357112 Good point, I'll try using dictionaries instead. Like you said, at first I thought exec() was pretty straight forward but after looking into it, there are a lot of limitations to it.

Comment: @ggorlen I'll look into that, thanks! I wasn't sure how to use dictionaries for this because like I said I wanted to dynamically create pages for each button. The buttons are made based on user input, so the number of buttons isn't predefined

Comment: Use `while true:` instead of `while x < len(path_list):`

Comment: @AlexMyladoor Dicts can handle dynamic, non-predefined things. They're like a collection of namespaced global variables, although I think in this case you want a list because you're counting 0, 1, 2, ... n for a collection of homogenous items.

Comment: @toyotaSupra: that's bad advice to use `while true`. For one, it's `True`, not `true`. For another, this will create an infinite loop.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I  typed too fast.